# Gallio: A simple way to extract required binaries?

Tags: .net, gallio

I store all of Gallio's binaries needed for a project in a SVN repository. I've been using Gallio for several years now and it's an excellent library.

The only real (and unique) problem with Gallio is that it is **very** bloated, with dozens of assemblies and other files that come in the package. In the very latest release (3.2.603) I counted **1041 files**, and that's just the `bin` directory. The package includes plugins for AutoCAD, for example, which I think 99.5% of people have no need for and I think should be part of some other, add-on package and not the main one.

Although in the past I managed to manually extract the stuff I needed for my work and add it to the version control, it becomes a real PITA to later upgrade it to a newer version - the subdirectory structure changes, files change and you never really know what files are the bare necessities and what files can safely be removed.

So basically, I'm looking for a way to make this simpler. Let's say I need the following functionality from Gallio:

1. Basic test framework.
2. Gallio.Echo as the command line runner. GUI runner is not really necessary to be included in the SVN.
3. VisualStudio integration (if any)
4. TestDriven.NET integration (if any).

Is there a sure way to extract only the files needed to cover the above?

Answer (score 1):

Here is good source of documentation about [**deployment of Gallio binaries**](http://gallio.org/wiki/doku.php?id=gallio%3ainstallation).

> To create a valid Gallio install, you need to copy all the plugins you are interested in to the target location. So for the minimum install you would have:

- Gallio.plugin
- Gallio.dll
- Gallio.pdb
- Gallio.xml
- Gallio.XmlSerializers.dll
- Gallio.Host.exe
- Gallio.Host.exe.config
- Gallio.Host.x86.exe
- Gallio.Host.x86.exe.config
- Gallio.Host.Elevated.exe
- Gallio.Host.Elevated.exe.config
- Gallio.Host.Elevated.x86.exe
- Gallio.Host.Elevated.x86.exe.config
- *Resources folder*

  - Assembly.ico
  - Container.ico
  - Fixture.ico
  - Gallio.ico
  - Test.ico
  - Unsupported.ico

Comment: @Yanni thanks for the link. However the list doesn't really cover any of the points in mentioned in the question (it doesn't even cover MbUnit). The link suggests looking into plugin configuration files and figuring out which dlls are needed. Not what I would call a "simple way". Frankly, from the viewpoint of somebody who also develops open-source software, I think Gallio's packaging system is a big failure.

Comment: The Gallio bundle comes with a convenient MSI installer (x86 or x64) where you can easily select which component you want to deploy. But it is also provided as a ZIP archive for manual deployment. In that case, the deployment is certainly not so easy, I agree.

Comment: The trunk (v3.3) contains a tool called Gallio.Copy which can be used to "install" Gallio (and MbUnit) into an arbitrary location. It's a bit rough around the edges, but please try it and let us know what you think.